# store objects in an array during foreach?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am looking to store some objects in an array during a foreach loop. The problem is creating a unique object each time. I have to have some kind of index appending the name of each object. Here is what I have:

```
function table_rows($html) {
        $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
        $table_rows = $dom->query('tr');
        $check_array = array();
        foreach ($table_rows as $key=>$table_row) {
            ($check_object . $key) = new check_class;
            ($check_object . $key)->check_method1($table_row);
            ($check_object . $key)->check_method2($table_row);
            ($check_object . $key)->check_method3($table_row);
            $check_array[] = (check_object . $key);
        }
    }
```

Am I even close?

Comment: It must be getting late... But, can't you just count the number of objects in the array and append 1?  much like array_push()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) for that:

```
function table_rows($html) {
    $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
    $table_rows = $dom->query('tr');
    $check_array = array();
    foreach ($table_rows as $key=>$table_row) {
        $object = new check_class;
        $object->check_method1($table_row);
        $object->check_method2($table_row);
        $object->check_method3($table_row);
        $check_array[] = $object;
    }
}
```

Of course naming the variable for an object instance `$object` is not very descriptive, but I hope you get the idea.

This works because the first assignment in the `for`-loop overwrites the "old" instance, so `$object` unique for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In case Jared Drake is right and what you mean is unique array keys, not object (variable) names.

```
 $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
 $table_rows = $dom->query('tr');
 $check_array = array();
 foreach ($table_rows as $key=>$table_row) {
        $check_object = new check_class;
        $check_object->check_method1($table_row);
        $check_object->check_method2($table_row);
        $check_object->check_method3($table_row);
        $check_array['check_object' . $key] = $check_object;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but can't you just use the [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) method to add each object to the end of the array in your `foreach` loop?

Comment: its not the array part im having trouble with, its creating the unique name for each object that I am having trouble with.